# How to float element next to line?

Tags: html, css, css-float

hei, I am looking to achieve something like this using html/css:
[image: this is what I'm trying to do]
In my case the "See chapter..." part should float on the right side of the text.

I thought I set a certain width for the normal text and then float the reference on the right side of it: like this:

HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum ‣3, Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p>
<div class="crossRef">see chapter bla</div>
```

CSS:

```
p{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
.crossRef{
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is an js fiddle that shows what I thought: https://jsfiddle.net/vbr3bL46/
But this apparently doesn't work that easily. The cross ref now is always at the top of this element, not where it actually is in text... does anyone have an idea how to achieve it?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with the code you've already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED FIDDLE - https://jsfiddle.net/vbr3bL46/8/

Doing it this way allows you to put the chapters in line with the citations.  Basically the `<p>` has a 35% padding to the right, then each citation has a negative right margin of 35% so it moves it, in-line, to the empty space on the right.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem 5 <span class="ref">see chapter 5</span> ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem 7 <span class="ref">see chapter 7</span>ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.row p {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 35%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row .ref {
    float: right;
    margin-right: -35%;
}
```

Comment: so with this the answer is basically: I have to decide whether I align this text to center, top or bottom of the paragraph, right?

Comment: This is specifically if you need to align the text on the right to the center based on the height of the text on the left.  If you don't need it vertically aligned, then I would go a different route and just float the divs.  This is only needed for vertically alignment of the right text.

Comment: yes, the question aimed to align it to the same line the cross reference is in. but that seems impossible according to your answer....

Comment: I'm sorry...I didn't even notice that you were trying to align it with a reference in the text.  You would probably need some JS for this one to calculate the height of the reference from the top of the container, and then apply that height to the reference on the right.  No simple CSS solution I could think of.

Comment: yeah. I guess it's designer's eye for whom it's obvious I wouldn't want the thing to be on top or bottom of container if posting that image... programmers eye looks at the code ;)

Comment: Couldn't let it slide...I posted an updated fiddle that has a solution for you.  You can put the citations inline with the text and then the CSS moves them out into the whit space in line with the reference.  Does that work?

Comment: ui. now I figured it works well if there is only a single cross-ref in a paragraph. but with multiple cross-ref in one paragraph it doesn't really work.... it mixes things up a bit.

Comment: The fiddle has 2 cross-refs in the same paragraph and it is working fine.  Maybe post a fiddle of what you have that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to NOT give float to your main text and put the float element on top of html:

```
.crossRef{
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    float: left;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

The margin and color are set just for better view.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vbr3bL46/1/)**

**EDITED**: As it looks I missunderstood the question I give now a more "flexible" answer. Youc an use a container with this properties:

```
.container {

    display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: flex-end;
}
```

Like this: **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vbr3bL46/6/)**

Comment: well, you said "hei, I am looking to achieve something like this using html/css: " then my solution is what I can see in the image. Then you say: " In my case the "See chapter..." part should float on the right side of the text.". So, the image is NOT what you want to achieve? I'm sorry if my english is not very good but your question is at the very least.. confusing

Comment: well. then if u don't understand maybe don't answer. but thanks anyways.

Comment: Well, I'm NOT the only one that give you this answer but hey, apologise again. Anyway I'm about to edit my answer to see if this time I got it (stupid me)

Comment: if I see correctly the answer is it won't work this way. I can only align to the top, bottom or center of the paragraph, not to the exact line in the paragraph....

Answer (score 0):

You will probaly have to add a container and adjust the structure slightly.

```css
p {
  width: 300px;
}
.crossRef {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="crossRef">see chapter bla</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum ‣3, Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem
    ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the display and adding a margin on top

```
p{
   width: 300px;
   float:left;    
}
.crossRef{
   margin-top:20px;
   width: 50px;
   display:inline-block;
}
```